# Jenkins ssh slave disconnect to make the task continue perform

Tags: jenkins, ssh, jenkins-agent

I have a iOS archive job on a mac slave which will take a long time sometimes 30min
The question is the ssh long connection often disconnect and caused the task fail.

Now I want to ask how can I do to avoid this question? What I'm looking for is when the long connection disconnect but the task continue to perform.
How can I do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Adding a keepAlive option is a [feature request since 2014](https://issues.jenkins-ci.org/browse/JENKINS-25793)

As proposed workarounds, this ticket includes:

> 1. Change the `/etc/ssh/ssh_config` by appending the following line to the end of this file. This tells the ssh client to send `nop` command periodically to avoid the ssh connection being disconnected.
>      The unit of 80 is seconds. You may tune this parameter based on your network condition.

```
ServerAliveInterval 80
```

> 2. In the Jenkins slave configuration page, change the Launch method to "`Launch slave via execution of command on the Master`". See the Jenkins built-in help for more details.
>
> So far, I haven't see any issues in this configuration. Hope this helps.

See also "[Remoting issues / SSH slaves](https://wiki.jenkins.io/display/JENKINS/Remoting+issue#Remotingissue-SSHslaves)".

Comment: Thx Vonc now I'm using  `launch agent via excution of command on the master`now My jenkins runing on a docker container, the master is Linux,Now the question is it can't display the emoji & ruby encode url return the error result, early connect via ssh is good,Do you know how can I fix this?

Comment: [here is the full description of my question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50784346/jenkins-launch-agent-via-excution-of-command-on-the-master-linux-cant-display-e)